# Can you land your private helicopter on Viking Line cruise ships?

Tags: cruising, luxury, helicopters, viking-line

Helicopter taxi services are everywhere near the baltic coasts. Can you take a helicopter taxi to a Viking Line cruise ship en route? Or is that not allowed? Are only ambulance helicopters allowed to land on the ships?

I recently asked a Viking Line customer service agent who gave me a quick "no" as an answer but I guess they're not trained to answer this type of question so I wonder what the real answer is if it's something else?

Comment: Anything is possible if you have the financial means

Comment: What makes you assume that customer service is not trained to answer such questions? The "real answer" is what customer service tells you. That's basically the whole idea behind customer services.

Comment: @gerrit's idea may have some merit: arrange another ship to be close and helicopter to *that;* then transfer to the cruise liner with a dinghy which is an everyday procedure (although, if it is in mid-cruise, they would need to stop for the transfer which seems unlikely, but I suppose they would normally stop for a helicopter landing as well).

Comment: It might be cheaper to fly all the way to the next country where the vessel stops than arranging and paying everyone involved an extraordinary sum.

Comment: I just had a funny thought but wonder if it's cheaper/easier to arrange a helicopter landing without the landing. I.e. flying to the ship and parachuting down... not the best idea, granted, but technically you're not landing with a helicopter...

Comment: It's kind of like asking your lawyer whether you can commit a bank robbery. Simple answer: no. The lawyer might have the know-how to get you acquitted but whether or not it is successful in court is a TBD situation. Same idea applies to your helicopter. You technically can with the right approvals and experience but calculating a strong gust of wind which blows your chopper into the tiki bar and killing dozens is not worth the money which you're paying.

Comment: If everyone were allowed to land their private helicopters on the ferries there'd be chaos. Imagine helicopter queues by the ferries. The risks of accidents without proper air traffic control would be enormous. Taking a helicopter to the ferry is fairly cheap, cheaper than buying the suite for full price.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus wind at open sea is usually stable. Offshore helicopters fly to and from oil service vessels and rigs daily. There's hundreds of offshore helicopter landings in the north sea daily. Accident don't happen every year.

Comment: **None** of the answers here have any factual information.

Comment: @Fattie The question already contains the answer; a swift No.

Comment: true enough, @MonkeyZeus - however, it's quite true that everyday customer service phone lines just wouldn't have a clue about anything mildly unusual.

Comment: @Fattie If one was in an actual position to want to land their helicopter on the ship then somehow I doubt that the standard customer service line would have been their first line of contact. It goes back to the old adage "Well, if you must ask...". The .1%, maybe yes but it doesn't apply to us so we have to accept the 99.9% answer.

Comment: @vidarlo Those choppers do that day in and day out and they have proper damage control in place. Somehow I doubt the cruise line would want the rented pilot of a famous basketball player to land on their ship.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Most things are trivial if you have an organization in place for it, even immensely complex tasks, such as running a nuclear reactor or an airport. But wind gusts is not that altogether common at sea... :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is probably no for all practical purposes.

In most countries, landing a helicopter on a vessel is a matter of agreement between those responsible for the vessel (e.g. owner *and* captain), and the aircraft. In addition, there may be flag state requirements on the vessel for manning of the helicopter landing deck with appropriately trained crew and firefighting equipment. Insurance companies may have a say on this as well, as no one wants to lose either a helicopter or a vessel.

So theoretically, you could probably reach some kind of agreement that would allow this, but it seems hugely impractical, prohibitively expensive, and practically impossible.

Comment: Furthermore, the noise of helicopters doesn't improve the experience of ticket paying passengers in the cruise.

Comment: @Pere Watching a helicopter land and take off would greatly improve the cruise experience for me.

Comment: Also, it seems pointlessly dangerous.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but this answer is simply quite incorrect, guys.  There's **nothing at all difficult**, in any way (expense, insurance, staff etc) about cruise ship + helicopter - simply see my answer.  It's a non-issue.  **By all means, the cruise brand in question may not allow it** - sure - But answers which say "it's too difficult!" are, simply, wrong. It's totally straightforward, cheap, trouble free, and not a big deal.

Comment: Your answer does in no way say that it's either. Having skilled helicopter cdeck crew on board costs money. Insurance costs money. And so forth. It's doable, as your answer (and vessels with helipads) indicate, but that doesn't say anything about the price or the organization needed. To put it another way: it's cheap if you have all it needs. But it's not cheap if you need extra helideck officers or extra insurance.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is yes you *can* and no you *may not*. Like [another answer states](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153522/81735), it is about permission and capabilities. They probably have the capabilities for the sake of emergencies. They don’t allow it for the sake of practicality.

Cruise ships contain a lot of guest. A lot of paying guests. A lot of paying guests who don’t own helicopters. Helicopters are *extremely* noisy. The engines alone can be ear piercing even from a distance. The rotor blade noise adds to that. That is not conducive to a relaxing cruise. Allowing a non-emergency landing for the sake of one guest would not be tolerated. If you have the bird, book your own private boat. They can at least take you to shore where there will probably be a heliport.

Answer (score 4):

[Technically helicopters can land](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nFK4bMdEuQ) (well, almost), but [Viking Line says](https://www.vikingline.com/the-group/safety/safety-on-board/) that

> In more serious cases we can use helicopter transport or evacuation boat.

Answer (score 4):

It's no big deal to have a chopper on a cruise ship, example:

http://travelweekly.com/Blogs/Dispatch/Riding-the-helicopter-on-the-Scenic-Eclipse

[image]

($400 a flight)

It's *unlikely* that the specific cruise brand asked about would have this service, or, it would be **widely advertised**. Like the other answerers, I have no factual information on whether the specific cruise brand asked about would have this service.

Comment: The Scenic Eclipse is an Expedition Yacht marketed as a “Discovery” Cruise liner.  ** The all-suite, 228-passenger cruise ship looks like a billionaire's superyacht and features an ice-strengthened hull, helipad (two Airbus H130 helicopters), aft marina (for water sports), a fleet of Zodiacs (large-capacity inflatable boats) and a 7-person submarine. **  This ship is for Antarctic Expedition cruises. Not exactly the same class as Viking.

Comment: Way fewer passengers onboard with probably half of them wanting to take the big, noisy bird over to disturb the penguins. The average cruise ship can have a helicopter land on it if they have the space. But, it is not worth the hassle to disturb the fare-paying self-loading cargo for the sake of a few people.